# How to show the diff output of two files in java spring mvc application?

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, text, diff

We have a requirement for our Java Spring MVC Application - we need to be able to show the visual diff output of two files residing on a network file share using our Web Application UI. Is this possible to do from MVC application? I have looked around and see that there are some java libraries like jmeld etc.

1. However, I have a very basic question - how can the view from the invocation of any of these tools [for instance, axis merge or other open source libraries] on the server side be shown on our Web Application UI?
2. Do we use the Client Side [javascript libraries] to show the visual diff of those 2 files on our Web UI?

Which of the above is the preferred & feasible way of showing the visual diff of the 2 text files to the user? Any pointers would greatly help me.

Thanks

Comment: `jmeld` is for swing UI, take a look on these [jhon diff algo](http://ejohn.org/projects/javascript-diff-algorithm/) , [JSBlend](http://jsblend.sourceforge.net/) & [prettydiff](http://prettydiff.com/)

Comment: Thank you Rembo for your suggestions. Prettydiff and JSBlend seem promising. I will look into them. Does anyone have any other inputs?